# Abbreviate values in report field in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a 2010 Access database that tracks volunteers for a charity group.
One of the columns in the VOLUNTEER table is called AVAILABILITY and the possible values are "seasonal" and "year-round".

I have created a report that lists out all the volunteer information, and it includes this column. The only problem I have is that I'd like to have the report abbreviate the values. Ideally "S" for seasonal and "YR" for year round in order to save space on the report. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course. You can either do it in a query and base the report on that or in the report itself:

```
 SELECT IIF([AVAILABILITY] = "Seasonal","S","Yr") As Avail 
 FROM MyTable
```

If you wish to set the control in your report, make sure to rename it to something other than Availability, say txtAvailability:

```
 = IIF([AVAILABILITY] = "Seasonal","S","Yr")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an IIF function, but this only allows for two availability options.  To allow for more in the future I would create a second table to look-up the abbreviations that are going to be displayed in your report.

Copy and paste this into the SQL Editor in Access to create such a table:

```
SELECT "Seasonal" AS Availability, "S" AS Abbreviation INTO tblAvailabilityOptions;
```

You are then going to create a query that your report will be based on that combines your main table with the new table you just created, joining on the "Availability" column:

```
SELECT tblMain.ID, tblMain.Volunteer, tblMain.Availability, tblAvailabilityOptions.Abbreviation
FROM tblMain INNER JOIN tblAvailabilityOptions ON tblMain.Availability = tblAvailabilityOptions.Availability;
```

If you know how to use the combobox lookup feature on your main table, this will be even easier.